# Can I transpile commonjs modules to es2015 before running webpack for tree shaking?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to add robust tree shaking to my company's application. From the webpack docs one of the requirements is the use of es2015 modules for import/export. My problem is we have some big shared component libraries. This is the main motivation for tree shaking as about 66% of the bundle size of our apps is coming from these shared dependencies, and we do not need all of it.

Anyway these libraries are already compiled and deployed to our in-house artifact repository. They were compiled using Babel and their import/export statements are now in commonjs (require/module.exports) format.

I'm looking at a variety of different options for dealing with this. The one I'm asking about here is if there is any way for me to have Babel recompile the libraries when webpack is bundling everything so that they return to es2015 module syntax and therefore work with tree shaking better?